# Rate limit a pubsub queue worker

Tags: node.js, message-queue, google-cloud-pubsub, rate-limiting

There is a scenario where a google **pubsub worker** will call a 3rd party API. This 3rd party API has **limit of 500 requests per minute**.

How can we handle this scenario.

- Rate limit the google pub-sub worker.(If its possible how we can achieve it?)
- Any other way available to check the limit before making the call to 3rd party API?

Please share if there is another option. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) is the tool designed for that. Instead of publishing your messages in a PubSub topic, create a task in a Cloud Task queue with the target URL.

On the task queue configuration, [define the rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate) and, out of the box, your feature is done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A question, what if we implement rate limiter in a worker based on redis and don't acknowledge the if rate limit exceeds?

Comment: Is it the behavior that you expect?

Comment: I believe so, only question in my mind is if I'll use redis base rateLimiter, could this cause race condition with multiple workers?

Comment: Redis is designed to work with different worker, the operation are atomic and you shouldn't have race condition with multiple worker. I didn't try it intensively to commit on that, but I'm confident enough to tell you that is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for your answer on redis, I believe it will work most likely. But I just came across token-bucket algorithm which can solve the rate limiting problem. To understand it fully and compare it with redis approach I was thinking about its implementation for multiple workers.
But came across a question, not sure where this token-bucket algorithm will be used in multiple workers. I mean we have to store the token count somewhere and share between workers.

Comment: Yes, store it in Memory store also!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution should be using the api-gateway, configure push notifications from the subscription to your limited api-gateway: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quotas-overview

When you reach the threshold, the messages will fail and get back to the queue. Be sure to configure several monitoring alerts to your pubsub unack message count and a DeadLetterQueue to avoid losing information.

Another solution might be a custom implementation in AppEngine, pulling messages with one instance of your subscriber App and keeping in memory the number of requests per date, not very resilient though. For a more resilient option consider using redis memorystore to keep the requests rate distributed between several instances, then you can use something like Cloud Functions.